# Why when I run robust standard errors I get NA values for t-scores, standard errors, etc

Tags: r, regression

I am working with the following [data](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/Card1995.Rdata) in Rstudio. 
I run a regression `minreg <- lm(lwage76~ed76 + exp76 + exp762, data = nlsdata)` and then look at the coefficients `coeftest(minreg, vcovHC)`. Up to this point every thing is fine. Then I run the same regression but including an extra variable: `minreg_a <- lm(lwage76~ed76 + exp76 + exp762 + kww, data = nlsdata)` Then to look at the coefficients `coeftest(minreg_a, vcovHC)`

```
t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  4.6051063         NA      NA       NA
ed76         0.0596900         NA      NA       NA
exp76        0.0699201         NA      NA       NA
exp762      -0.0021611         NA      NA       NA
kww11        0.3504745         NA      NA       NA
kww12        0.0468874         NA      NA       NA
kww13        0.2146929         NA      NA       NA
kww14        0.0623738         NA      NA       NA
kww15        0.0298164         NA      NA       NA
kww16        0.2308240         NA      NA       NA
kww17        0.1766641         NA      NA       NA
kww18        0.2579742         NA      NA       NA
kww19        0.2125317         NA      NA       NA
kww20        0.2498308         NA      NA       NA
kww21        0.2670052         NA      NA       NA
kww22        0.3581900         NA      NA       NA
kww23        0.5047055         NA      NA       NA
kww24        0.2953582         NA      NA       NA
kww25        0.3738028         NA      NA       NA
kww26        0.3819417         NA      NA       NA
kww27        0.3533177         NA      NA       NA
kww28        0.4772736         NA      NA       NA
kww29        0.4024529         NA      NA       NA
kww30        0.3988244         NA      NA       NA
kww31        0.4426652         NA      NA       NA
kww32        0.4117452         NA      NA       NA
kww33        0.4294092         NA      NA       NA
kww34        0.4356410         NA      NA       NA
kww35        0.4399743         NA      NA       NA
kww36        0.4630381         NA      NA       NA
kww37        0.4779400         NA      NA       NA
kww38        0.4867528         NA      NA       NA
kww39        0.5439840         NA      NA       NA
kww4         0.1968018         NA      NA       NA
kww40        0.5427968         NA      NA       NA
kww41        0.5436628         NA      NA       NA
kww42        0.6319893         NA      NA       NA
kww43        0.5522148         NA      NA       NA
kww44        0.5540705         NA      NA       NA
kww45        0.5897991         NA      NA       NA
kww46        0.5372961         NA      NA       NA
kww47        0.7583224         NA      NA       NA
kww48        0.8191181         NA      NA       NA
kww49        0.5448992         NA      NA       NA
kww50        0.7070670         NA      NA       NA
kww51        0.6892674         NA      NA       NA
kww52        0.6381098         NA      NA       NA
kww53        0.5876115         NA      NA       NA
kww54        0.7680939         NA      NA       NA
kww55        1.1111694         NA      NA       NA
kww56        0.5049158         NA      NA       NA
kww6         0.0831418         NA      NA       NA
kww8         0.3058253         NA      NA       NA
kwwNA        0.3973854         NA      NA       NA
```

I have one question here: why the NA outputs; these only occur when I try to run robust standard errors?

This has totally got me boggled

Comment: Can you post a re-producible example downloading and loading the data?  I get the following error when trying to load your data into R: Error in load("Card1995.Rdata") : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘Card1995.Rdata’ has magic number ''
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp , that's because the data are really text - try saving as `.txt` and using `read.table()` to load them.

Comment: Where is the `coeftest` function and also the `vcovHC` argument that is passed to it defined?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you have probably come across the answer by now, but I just came across the same problem with a stratified analysis that I performed. On the entire dataset I could compute robust standard errors with HC0 to HC5, but when stratifying by a relatively small subset (~10% of the sample, n~2300) I could only compute robust SEs with HC0 and HC1 (ie. I got NAs for HC2 and above, just as you did). The problem (I assume) had to do with the co-variance between two variables in my model, ethnicity and income (both factors). Within this subset, many people in minority ethnicities only belonged to a couple levels of the income variable, and vice-versa. When I removed income or ethnicity, or adjusted my stratification so that this subset was twice the size, everything worked (ie. no NAs).

I realize this is a very anecdotal answer, but I hope it helps. If this makes sense to someone with a better understanding of these procedures, perhaps they can provide a more comprehensive response.